# Snowflake:Pattern date search read from S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Requirement:** Need to fetch only the latest file everyday example here its 20200902 file

Example Files in S3:

```
@stagename/2020/09/reporting_2020_09_20200902000335.gz
@stagename/2020/09/reporting_2020_09_20200901000027.gz
```

**Code:**

```
select distinct metadata$filename from 
@stagename/2020/09/
(file_format=>APP_SKIP_HEADER,pattern=>'.*/reporting_*20200902*.gz');
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work no matter what the naming conventions of the files. Since your files appear to have a naming convention based on date and are one per point in time, you may not need to use the date to do this as you could use the name. You'll still want to use the result_scan approach.

I haven't found a way to get the date for a file in a stage other than using the LIST command. The docs say that FILE_NAME and FILE_ROW_NUMBER are the only available metadata in a select query. In any case, that approach reads the data, and we only want to read the metadata.

Since a LIST command is a metadata query, you'll need to query the result_scan to use a where clause.

One final issue that I ran into while working on a project: the last_modified date in the LIST command is in format that requires a somewhat long conversion expression to convert to timestamp. I made a UDF to do the conversion so that it's more readable. If you'd prefer putting the expression directly in the SQL, that's fine too.

First, create the UDF.

```
create or replace function LAST_MODIFIED_TO_TIMESTAMP(LAST_MODIFIED string) 
returns timestamp_tz
as
$$
    to_timestamp_tz(left(LAST_MODIFIED, len(LAST_MODIFIED) - 4) || ' ' || '00:00', 'DY, DD MON YYYY HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
$$;
```

Next, list the files in your stage or subdirectory of the stage.

```
list @stagename/2020/09/
```

Before running any other query in the session, run this one on the last query ID. You can of course run it any time in 24 hours if you specify the query ID explicitly.

```
select "name", 
       "size",
       "md5",
       "last_modified",
       last_modified_to_timestamp("last_modified") LAST_MOD
from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
order by LAST_MOD desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Nice detailed answer, just small note I think you can simplify reading timestamp as

to_timestamp(LEFT("last_modified",25),'DY, DD MON YYYY HH:MI:SS') LAST_MOD

Comment: Yes, that will work. My UDF was originally intended to convert to UTC.